# ggplot change the x axis label colors dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is the test code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df<- data.frame(PCP = c("BOB","FRED","ED","Other"),
                closed = c(42,64,45,1812), 
                total= c(53,81,58,3188), 
                percentage = c(.7924,.7901,.7758,.5683),
                row= c(1, 2, 3,4),
                color =c("0099FF","#CCCCCC","#CCCCCC","#660033"),
                color_fill = c("99","0","0","98"
                ))

col  <- c(
  "99" = "#0099FF",
  "98" = "#660033", 
  "0" = "#CCCCCC" 
)

df %>%  
  arrange(desc(percentage)) %>% 
  mutate(PCP = PCP,
         closed = closed,
         total = total,
         percentage = percentage,
         row = row,
         color = color,
         color_fill = color_fill) -> df1

ggplot(df1,aes(x=PCP, y = percentage,fill=color_fill, color = color)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x ="PCP Name",
       y = "Percentage of Gap Closures",
       title =  "TOP 10 PCPs")+
   scale_fill_manual(values = col)+
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size=15),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face= "italic"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = col ))
```

My goal is to match x axis labels with the bar colors.

I have attempted solutions from,
[Matching axis.text labels to colors contained in data frame variable in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669663/matching-axis-text-labels-to-colors-contained-in-data-frame-variable-in-ggplot)

However when attempting the factor levels portion, I get an error because my actual data contains other values that utilize the same #CCCCCC color code.

Below is the output of the attached code.

[image: Results]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: There was an answer posted earlier that i managed to copy and paste before it was deleted. The code works well with the 4 names listed, however once i add additional names, the color coding is off again. Seems like a step in the right direction, i'm not getting multiple burgandy or blue colors anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is here (I mean I understand that you provide the colors in the wrong order; in the theme you would have to use `col[as.integer(df$color)]` to mimic the order of the factor but I have no clue why) but I have a workaround that works well.

One less known function in `ggplot2` is `ggplot_build`. Using this you can, as the name suggests, build the plot, which means you can extract the values you want from it. Based on this I wrote a little function which can do what you want.

```r
axis_text_color <- function(plot, col = "fill") {
  c <- ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]
  plot +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = c[[col]]))
}
```

The way you use it is by first saving the plot in an object:

```r
library(tidyverse)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(
    x = PCP,
    y = percentage,
    fill = color_fill,
    color = color
  )) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "PCP Name",
       y = "Percentage of Gap Closures",
       title =  "TOP 10 PCPs") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face = "italic")
  )
```

And then calling the function on that plot:

```r
axis_text_color(plot)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This worked amazingly well! Thank you so much, you just saved me from going into complete madness haha @JBGruber

Comment: Factors in `ggplot2` annoy me pretty regularly as well. Just after writing I found another way to solve it. In the theme, use `col[as.integer(df$color)]` to sort the col vector in the same order as the factor `df$color`. But fell free to use the function instead!

Comment: i tried the second solution and something is off again. Ill just stick to the first method you provided. Again thank you so much! @JBGruber

Comment: I realized I renamed the df. With the original example it should be `col[as.integer(df1$color)]`...

Answer (score 0):

If possible, would take out `color` from your `df` so you don't duplicate with your `col` vector.

You would need to order your `color_fill` based on `PCP` (the order based on factor, alphabetical).

Finally, would use `as.character` to create a character vector instead of factor, and use as look up reference for `col`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df<- data.frame(PCP = c("BOB","FRED","ED", "Alfred", "Other"),
                closed = c(42,64,45,100,1812), 
                total= c(53,81,58,100,3188), 
                percentage = c(.7924,.7901,.7758,.3,.5683),
                row= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                #color =c("0099FF","#CCCCCC","#CCCCCC", "#00EE00", "#660033"),
                color_fill = c("99","0","0","97","98")
                )

col  <- c(
  "99" = "#0099FF",
  "98" = "#660033", 
  "97" = "#00FF00",
  "0" = "#CCCCCC" 
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=PCP, y=percentage, fill=color_fill, color = color_fill)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x ="PCP Name",
       y = "Percentage of Gap Closures",
       title =  "TOP 10 PCPs")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col)+
  scale_color_manual(values = col)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size=15),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face= "italic"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = col[as.character(df$color_fill[order(df$PCP)])]))
```

[image: plot with text label color matching bars]

Comment: Sorry about deleting earlier. Hope this may still be helpful.