# Custom x-axis labels not applying correct custom x-axis colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, ggtext

In my df, I need the two x-axis labels under "subset" = "Initial" to be coloured grey50 (like the two bars on the left) and the two x-axis labels under "subset" = "Processed" to be coloured midnightblue (like the two bars on the right).

Code:

```
df_TP <- data.frame(
  categ = c("initial_t_tp", "processed_t_tp", "initial_v_tp", "processed_v_tp"),
  group = rep("TP", 4),
  absolute = c(86, 85, 21, 21),
  percentage = c(84.16, 84.16, 84.00, 84.00),
  col = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
  subset = c("initial", "processed", "initial", "processed")
)

labels_tp <- c(
  "initial_t_tp" = "Training",
  "initial_v_tp" = "Validation",
  "processed_v_tp" = "Validation",
  "processed_t_tp" = "Training"
)

a <- ifelse(df_TP$col == 0, "grey50", "midnightblue")

# Create the bar plot with separation
ggplot(
  df_TP,
  aes(x = categ, y = absolute, fill = subset)
) +
geom_col(aes(fill = subset)) +
labs(x = NULL, y = "# detected events") +
scale_fill_manual(
  values = c("initial" = "grey50", "processed" = "midnightblue")
) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
  axis.title.y = element_text(
    size = 30, color = "grey50",
    vjust = 2, hjust = 0.95),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size = 25, colour = "grey50"),
  axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(
    size = 25, vjust = 3, colour = a
  ),
  strip.text = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey85"),
  panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  legend.position = "none",
  plot.margin = margin(l = 20, 0, 0, 0),
  aspect.ratio = 1/0.9
) +
coord_cartesian(
  ylim = c(0, 90), clip = 'off'
) +
facet_grid(
  . ~ subset, scales = "free_x", switch = "x",
) +
scale_y_continuous(
  limits = c(0, 90), breaks = seq(0, 90, by = 30)
) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_tp)
```

This outputs:

[image]

I'm unable to understand why only Validation is being coloured (both Validation from Initial and Validation from Processed). As seen in my dataframe, the only way it can separate between Training and Validation is by considering a threshold on the y-axis values (Validation is always lower than Training).

I have tried applying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors) for both a categorical and a numerical condition (which is why the sole reason I created "col" with 0 and 1). I tried the ifelse with "col" and "subset", with no luck.

I have also tried the convoluted solution by Ben in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826366/ggplot-change-the-x-axis-label-colors-dynamically) post:

```
cols <- c(
  "initial_t_tp" = "grey50",
  "initial_v_tp" = "grey50",
  "processed_v_tp" = "midnightblue",
  "processed_t_tp" = "midnightblue"
)

colour = cols[as.character(df_TP$categ[order(df_TP$categ)])]
```

But no luck.

I understand this post is prone to downvotes because this question has been asked before and have spent the last two hours trying to avoid an extra post. At this point, I'm making mistakes out of tiredness.

I am assuming my code has a little more elements than other questions made here and something is making the code override the dictated logic in favour of either only training or only validation. But what?

Comment: *"I need the two values under "subset" = "Initial" to be coloured grey50 and the two values under "subset" = "Processed" to be coloured midnightblue"*. They are exactly those colors. Do you mean the axis labels or the columns themselves? The issue (I think) is that your `a` is in a different order than what is presented on the plot.

Comment: @r2evans the two grey bars on the left are "initial" and the two blue bars on the right are "processed". I need the axis labels to be coloured the same. I have edited my post.

Comment: I think changing the order of `a` is fragile, and if you add/shift data then it will need to be reordered again. I suggest baking the colored labels into the data itself (esp since you're using `ggtext`).

Comment: @r2evans can you elaborate on what "baking" means?

Comment: You're right thanks, was just a simple solution if the data structure was "simple"

Comment: @BarbaraPerezdeAraújo “[bake into](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/153444/3574)” means to add/hard-code the colour information into the data itself.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph, I was working on the answer and didn't get to that comment yet ... Yes, though in my case it is _programmatically_ coded into the data so that the colors and such are available consistently, regardless of the order of the data, columns, categories, etc.

Comment: @BarbaraPerezdeAraújo, see my edited (and since-undeleted) answer, I hope that explains what didn't work and one way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using external vectors (`a` here) in non-NSE elements of ggplot2 expressions can be problematic, since the order of how `a` is applied is not necessarily (often is not at all) the same as the order of the columns. I suggest putting the colors into the frame itself.

I'm inferring that you want "Training" before "Validation", so we'll need to control the order using `factor` as well.

By "baking" (my word) the axis label into the data itself, we can (a) include its color, (b) control its order, and (c) remove the need to change the labels with `scale_x_discrete`.

(No longer using `a` or `labels_tp`.)

Here's the "baked in data":

```r
library(dplyr)
df_TP |>
  mutate(
    xcol = if_else(col == 0, "grey50", "midnightblue"),
    xaxs = if_else(grepl("_t_", categ), "Training", "Validation"),
    xaxs = reorder(sprintf("<span style = 'color:%s;'>%s</span>", xcol, xaxs),
                   match(xaxs, c("Training", "Validation")))
  )
#            categ group absolute percentage col    subset         xcol                                                  xaxs
# 1   initial_t_tp    TP       86      84.16   0   initial       grey50         <span style = 'color:grey50;'>Training</span>
# 2 processed_t_tp    TP       85      84.16   1 processed midnightblue   <span style = 'color:midnightblue;'>Training</span>
# 3   initial_v_tp    TP       21      84.00   0   initial       grey50       <span style = 'color:grey50;'>Validation</span>
# 4 processed_v_tp    TP       21      84.00   1 processed midnightblue <span style = 'color:midnightblue;'>Validation</span>
```

(I'm using `dplyr` here, though this can be easily adapted to base R in three steps: (1) change `mutate` to `transform`, (2) change `if_else` to `ifelse`, and (3) break the second `xaxs` assignment into a new `|> transform(..)`, since transform does not "see" the previous definition of `xaxs`.)

With this, we can remove the dependence on `a` and `labels_tp`, and instead tell ggplot and `ggtext` to format the axis labels directly.

```r
# Create the bar plot with separation
df_TP |>
  mutate(
    xcol = if_else(col == 0, "grey50", "midnightblue"),
    xaxs = if_else(grepl("_t_", categ), "Training", "Validation"),
    xaxs = reorder(sprintf("<span style = 'color:%s;'>%s</span>", xcol, xaxs),
                   match(xaxs, c("Training", "Validation")))
  ) |>
  ggplot(
    # df_TP,
    aes(x = xaxs, y = absolute, fill = subset)
  ) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = subset)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "# detected events") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("initial" = "grey50", "processed" = "midnightblue")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      size = 30, color = "grey50",
      vjust = 2, hjust = 0.95),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 25, colour = "grey50"),
    axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(
      size = 25, vjust = 3 #, colour = a
    ),
    strip.text = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey85"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.margin = margin(l = 20, 0, 0, 0),
    aspect.ratio = 1/0.9
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(
    ylim = c(0, 90), clip = 'off'
  ) +
  facet_grid(
    . ~ subset, scales = "free_x", switch = "x",
    ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 90), breaks = seq(0, 90, by = 30)
  ) #  +
  # scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_tp)
```

[image: grob with corrected labels]

Comment: Thank you so, so much for the patience and thorough explanations. This solved my problem and I'll remember this in my future ggplot2 endeavours :)